# How to allow the user to create their own credentials to log in React

Tags: reactjs

I am a bit lost and I don't know how to allow the user to create their own credentials to log in using the login form.
Any suggestions?

At the moment the login works with a user and password created by me and inserted in the code you see below.

Instead, I would like the user to be able to create a personal username and password.
I did some research but I'm a little confused and I'm not sure what to look for to fix the problem.

````
    const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState({});
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // User login info
    const database = [{
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pass'
    }
    ];

    const errors = {
        uname: "invalid username",
        pass: "invalid password"
    };


    const handlesubmit=(event)=>{

        event.preventDefault();
        var { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];

        const userData = database.find((user) => user.username === uname.value);

        if (userData) {
            if (userData.password !== pass.value) {
              // Invalid password 
              setErrorMessages({ name: "pass", message: errors.pass });
            } else {
              setIsSubmitted(true);
              navigate("/Profile");
            }
          } else {
            setErrorMessages({ name: "uname", message: errors.uname });
        }

    };

    const renderErrorMessage = (name) =>
    name === errorMessages.name && (
      <div className="error">{errorMessages.message}</div>
    );

    return (
        <div className="main-login">
            <div className="login-container">
                <img src="" alt="" />
                <h2>Login Page</h2>
                <div className="form-container">
                    <form onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
                    <label for="username">Username</label> <br />
                    <input className="loginInput" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="uname" id="username" required /> <br/>
                    {renderErrorMessage("uname")}
                    <label for="password">Password</label> <br />
                    <input className="loginInput" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="pass" id="password" required /> <br/>
                    {renderErrorMessage("pass")}
                    <button className="loginBtn" type="submit">Accedi</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <p>o <Link to='/Register'>Registrati qui</Link></p> 
                 <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use an external database to do this kind of thing as you'll have to store each User's credentials. Another option is an authentication service.

I'd recommend using Firebase Authentication, it's super easy to use and you can use Google accounts, email and password and a number of other options.

Check it out [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)

There's also plenty of resources on YouTube for Firebase.